# How can I have auto-completion of package names for ubuntu-bug?

Tags: bug-reporting, 17.10

Is it possible to tab auto-complete the `ubuntu-bug` command with the name of the package to be reported?

**Example:**

Typing in `ubuntu-bug gnome` and pressing Tab should give me a list of packages that begin with `gnome` in the list.

Comment: It can sometimes be difficult to identify which is the failing package. Is this your problem? Or is the problem simply, that you don't want to type the whole name of the program package? Which version are you running? Auto-completion works for me in the latter case, when  I test in 16.0.4 LTS.

Comment: The latter. I tried it on 17.10 but it is not working for me [1](https://www.useloom.com/share/21960ad37e19438d9cd6acda07db9190).

Comment: I tested in Ubuntu 17.10: It works for me in an `x11` session as well as in a `wayland` session with program packages that belong to Ubuntu, for example firefox: `ubuntu-bug firef` will be completed to `ubuntu-bug firefox`. Bash completion works even with packages that belong to a PPA (for example ppa:mkusb/unstable). This system was installed as a fresh installation. `ubuntu-bug gnome` and pressing TAB twice produces the output `Display all 282 possibilities? (y or n)` and the next tab starts `more` (displaying the possibilities).  **Is yours an upgraded system from a previous version?**

Comment: Thanks! I guess in this case I will reinstall the system. I installed from Ubuntu 17.10 Beta 2.

Comment: Good luck :-) and please let us know the result: Share your solution if successful; ask for more help if there are still problems.

Comment: Are you using a terminal? Did you change the default terminal shell from bash?

Comment: I am using gnome-terminal with default Bash.